# MongoDb indexes optimizing

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB to do a project which stores some doc-like data parsed from the log and support some complex query from MongoDB. But when I run a query, I met a very interesting problem. 
The query is like this:

```
db.actions.find({
    Created: { $gte: 1470208679, $lte: 1470212279 }, 
    ActionType: "COMMENT_CREATE", 
    UserAgent: "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0" 
}).limit(200)
```

I had built two compound indexes, one was `{ ActionType: 1, Created: 1 }`, the other was `{ UserAgent: 1, Created: 1 }`. Initially, I thought MongoDB should find the optimist index to do the query. But from the log, unfortunately it did not.

I used `explain()` to find the reason. The result from mongo client is as follows

```
> db.actions.find({
      Created: { $gte: 1470208679, $lte: 1470212279 }, 
      ActionType: "COMMENT_CREATE", 
      UserAgent: "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0" 
}).limit(200).explain()
```

**Result**

```
{
    "cursor" : "IndexCursor UserAgent_1_Created_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 167,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1552,
    "nscanned" : 1552,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2426,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2426,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 32,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "UserAgent" : [
            [
                "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0",
                "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0"
            ]
        ],
        "Created" : [
            [
                1470208679,
                1470212279
            ]
        ]
    },
}
```

And if we use hint to use another index, the result is

```
db.actions.find({
    Created: { $gte: 1470208679, $lte: 1470212279 }, 
    ActionType: "COMMENT_CREATE", 
    UserAgent: "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0" 
}).limit(200).hint({ ActionType: 1, Created: 1 }).explain()
```

**Result**

```
{
    "cursor" : "IndexCursor ActionType_1_Created_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 167,
    "nscannedObjects" : 13988,
    "nscanned" : 13988,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 13988,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 13988,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 127,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "ActionType" : [
            [
                "COMMENT_CREATE",
                "COMMENT_CREATE"
            ]
        ],
        "Created" : [
            [
                1470208679,
                1470212279
            ]
        ]
    },
}
```

We can see that the mongo client automatically used the `{ "UserAgent": 1, Created: 1 }` index, which is the best choice, the `nscanned` was far less from the `{ 'ActionType': 1, Created: 1 }` index. Till now, everything seems perfect. But strange things were found from the log when we used the query from our project instead of from mongo command line, it chose the 
`{ 'ActionType': 1, Created: 1 }` index.

```
Wed Aug  3 16:17:59.442 [conn1517] query actions query: { $query: { $and: [ { Created: { $gte: 1470208679 } }, { Created: { $lte: 1470212279} }, { ActionType: "COMMENT_CREATE" }, { UserAgent: "osee2unifiedRelease/482 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0" } ] }} ntoreturn:200 ntoskip:0 nscanned:13988 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:147591 nreturned:167 reslen:68229 147ms
```

Can anyone help me with this situation?

Comment: I don't know if it is because Mongodb cached the {ActionType:1,Created:1} plan in its first query, (Maybe the in the first time, {ActionType:1,Created:1}  scanned less the {'UserAgent':1, Created:1} when data set is very small), I see since 2.6 there is a method called planCacheClear , but I am using 2.4. Anyway to refresh the cache?

Comment: Drop and recreate indexes on the collection or restart the server.

Comment: The restart part is what I can understand, but why should I recreate the indexes? any hints?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/#plan-cache-flushes)